# Image Size wrong during upload

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I am currently in the middle of developing the front page for a online store. I am trying to resize the width of the image to expand it across the full width of the page, however the image will not expand any further than 960px I need to expand it 1440px. I have tried using both the CSS and HTML to correct this but I am finding no luck. As well as that I looked within the Wordpress media library to see if I checked the right box when uploading so that it is the full size, I am short on ideas and am clueless on what to do now.

[image: This is my CSS for the Image]

[image: This is all my HTML, I have tried resizing it using styling within the HTML]

[This is what I mean by the image not expanding to the full width of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RmZO.png)

Comment: In the Dashboard, under Settings > Media, what is 'large' set to?

Comment: You need to adjust your content width set in functions.php

Answer (score 1):

The maximum width of an image displayed in content is not just determined by the image sizes you set or CSS settings, it is also determined by the content width set in functions.php through code similar to the following

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 960;
}
```

You need to set this to your required size as well in order for the image to display correctly with this bigger image width. Without setting that accordingly, even if you set your image sizes correctly, the biggest an image will be in the content area will be 960 px as in example.

You also need to remember, images can be up-scaled, so any image smaller than your new size will only be as wide as its original size

Answer (score -2):

Did you try `width:100%;` in your css?